# Linking Access Database with arcgis 10 and is it more efficient?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, ms-access

I have currently started working for a fisheries consultancy. They have all their data eg. catch rates, fishing effort, gear types in an Access database. Existing and previous projects have map/mxd files saved on the c drive.

Requests to edit  an existing map will come through e.g update this map with new fishing effort data. They currently run a query in Access, then import the result into excel and create a table, they then finally add the table to arcgis desktop 10 and then convert into a shapefile by extracting xy coordinates.

Wouldn't it be simpler to link the Access database to arc and select the data required for the update directly making this mundain task quicker?

And isn't it simple to run a access like data query within arc?

Comment: Yes and Yes to your questions! Exporting to Excel is a waste of time and you don't have an ObjectID field which you will require if you do any selections.

Comment: Thank you, I will be updating their current work flow in the future. The catch is the company bills by the hour and isn't keen on speeding the existing work flow up.